# Add landscape format to RichTextBox content saved as RTF

Tags: vb.net, rtf, landscape

I save the content of a `RichTextBox` as `RTF` file but I need to set the page in `landscape`.

Looking for `RTF` and `Landscape` on the web I found something useful but I wasn't able to adapt to my needs:

My `RTF` file looks like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1040\f0\fs24\par
 Amount     Start      End        Rate    Days    Result\par
 \'80 1.000,00 04/11/2015 31/12/2015 0,50%     58    \'80 0,79\par
 \'80 1.000,00 01/01/2016 03/11/2016 0,20%    308    \'80 1,69\par
\par
 Total    \'80 2,48\par
}
```

And I found the following `RTF` example with `landscape` format:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Courier;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\landscape
\paperw15840\paperh12240\margl720\margr720\margt720\margb720
\tx720\tx1440\tx2880\tx5760
This line is the default color\line
\tab this line has 1 tab\line
\tab\tab this line has 2 tabs\line
\tab\tab\tab this line has 3 tabs\line
\tab\tab\tab\tab this line has 4 tabs\line
\cf2
\tab This line is red and has a tab before it\line
\cf1
\page This line is the default color and the first line on page 2
}
```

I've tried to add `\landscape` to my output string in many different locations but still not able to make it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `\landscape` by itself isn't enough, you also need to set the paper width and height to be landscape:

```
\landscape\paperw15840\paperh12240
```